# PHP, MySQL - Storing data locally vs Fetching from remote every time

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a dashboard application that has PHP backend and javascript frontend. Data is read from multiple sources and I have access to databases of all the sources. 
While designing the application, is it a good idea to store remote data locally instead of hitting the remote database everytime the application has a request?

1. Store locally? Reason being the data is not live. I can write a cron to run in the background to update the data every 5 min and the application always will read the data from local DB thereby giving faster load times.
2. Read from remote every time? Since I have direct database access to all these remote DB's, I do not notice any performance gain of storing data locally over fetching from remote everytime.

Which approach scales better?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called "caching." It's a common optimization.

Fetching data remotely is much more expensive than getting it out of a local cache.

You should learn the [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832).

The tricky part of caching is knowing when you need to discard the local cached copy of data and re-fetch it from the remote database. This is a hard problem with no single answer.

There's an old joke attributed to Phil Karlton:

> “There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.”